# Converting a Variant Array to a Dynamic Array

Tags: arrays, delphi

I'm trying to convert a variant array (of doubles, but it could be anything I guess) to a dynamic array. I usually use the DynArrayFromVariant and DynArrayToVariant procedures, but in this case my variant arrays are 1 based. These two functions only seem to work on 0 based arrays. Any idea how I could do what I need to do?

Comment: Call SetLength to allocate the dynamic array and then populate it with a for loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know the type of your array elements you can write more efficient (while less generic) code:

```
function DoubleDynArrayFromVarArray(const V: Variant): TDoubleDynArray;
var
  P: Pointer;
  Count: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if not VarIsArray(V) or (VarType(V) and varTypeMask <> varDouble) or
    (VarArrayDimCount(V) <> 1) then
    raise EVariantInvalidArgError.Create(SVarInvalid);

  Count := VarArrayHighBound(V, 1) - VarArrayLowBound(V, 1) + 1;
  if Count = 0 then
    Exit;

  P := VarArrayLock(V);
  try
    SetLength(Result, Count);
    Move(P^, Result[0], Count * SizeOf(Double));
  finally
    VarArrayUnlock(V);
  end;
end;
```